# Почему не получается удалить атрибут экземпляра класса, унаследованный от родителя, но в самом классе его удалить можно?

Tags: python

```
class Point3D:
    x = 7
    y = 5
    z = 5


e = Point3D()
print(e.z)
delattr(e, 'z')
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Во-первых, в приведённом вами коде нет ни наследования, ни какого-либо родителя. Вероятно, вы имели в виду не "наследование", а "инстанцирование экземпляра"? Это два совершенно разных понятия.

Что касается вашего вопроса: дело в том, что в вашем случае экземпляр не обладает собственным аттрибутом "z". Он может обращаться к соответствующему аттрибуту класса, но сам его не имеет. Поэтому и удалять его нельзя.

Answer (score 2):

Вы определили `z` как атрибут **класса**, потому его невозможно удалить ссылкой на *объект* этого класса.

Для определения `z` как атрибута **объекта** этого класса, возможно применить разные подходы:

1. Определить аттрибут *в классе*, но как атрибут им созданных объектов, *с начальным значением:*

   ```
   class Point3D:
       x = 7
       y = 5
       def __init__(self):
           self.z = 5
   ```

   В этом случае ваше последующие команды не нужно изменить.

---

2. Определить аттрибут *в классе,* опять как атрибут ним созданных объектов, но позволяющий изменить его значение *прямо во время создания объектов:*

   ```
   class Point3D:
       x = 7
       y = 5
       def __init__(self, z=5):
           self.z = z
   ```

   Ваше последующие команды опять не нужно изменить, но возможно создать объект
   *с другим начальным значением:*

   ```
     e = Point3D(127)       # или e = Point3D(z=127)
   ```

---

3. Совсем не определить `z` в классе:

   ```
    class Point3D:
        x = 7
        y = 5
   ```

   а определить его только *после создания объекта:*

   ```
    e = Point3D
    e.z = 5             # создание аттрибута z только для объекта е
   ```

---

---

*Примечание:*

Лучше всего определить и переменные `x` и  `y` как переменные объектов этого класса, например так:

```
class Point3D:
   def __init__(self, x=0, y=0, z=0):
       self.x = x
       self.y = y
       self.z = z
```

Comment: Так "e" и есть имя объекта, а "z" - аттрибут. У автора здесь всё правильно было, а вот вы как раз всё перепутали

Comment: @Xander, спасибо, я совершенно изменил мой ответ.

Answer (score 0):

```
class Point3D:
    x = 7
    y = 6
    z = 5


e = Point3D()
print(e.z)

print(hasattr(e, 'z')) # До удаления
delattr(Point3D, 'z')
print(hasattr(e, 'z')) # После удаления
```

Comment: Вопрос был почему нельзя удалить из экземпляра класса )

Comment: И кстати, ответ на Ваш вопрос почему в экземпляре удалять нельзя. Насколько я знаю, только потому что экземпляры наследуются, якобы создав этот экземпляр он не становится полностью независим от класса. Ну НАВЕРНОЕ так))

Comment: Вот ссылка, можете тебе поможет это https://coderoad.ru/29034270/%D0%A3%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B1%D1%83%D1%82-%D0%B8%D0%B7-%D1%8D%D0%BA%D0%B7%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%BF%D0%BB%D1%8F%D1%80%D0%B0-%D0%BA%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%81%D0%B0-python

Comment: Ну, это не мой вопрос, я просто уточнил